# Is $G$ a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z^n= 1 \ \text{for some  positive integer}\  n \}$, with group structure given by multiplication of complex numbers.

Choose the correct option:

$1.$ $ G$ is  a  group of finite order

$2.$ $ G$ is a group of infinite order, but every element of G has finite order

$3.$ $G$ is a cyclic group

$4.$ None of these

## My attempt: options $1, 3$ are true.

$G$ consists of all $n$-roots of unity for some positive integer $n$.  Any element of $G$ can be uniquely written as $e^{({\frac{2i\pi k}{n}})}$ for some $k\in \{ 0,\ldots ,n-1\}$ that is prime with $n$.

$\exp\left( \frac{2k\pi i}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left( \frac{2\pi ki}{n}\cdot n\right)=\exp(2\pi k i)=1$

So  $G$ is a cyclic group and $G$ is a group of finite order.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: thanks u @DonThousand..

Comment: I believe the set contains all roots of unity of ALL the natural numbers... Think again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! $G$ is not cyclic( If it were, then upto isomorphism, $G \sim (\Bbb Z,+)$ .Note that $-1$ has order $2$ in $G$ but in $(\Bbb Z,+)$, there is no such element )

The group $G$ is actually union of all $n$-th root of unity. That is $$G:=\cup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{z \in \Bbb C: z^n=1\}$$

So $G$ is a group of infinite order. Also note that , for $z \in G$, order of $z$ is atmost $n$, so second option is true!